# Magento2.4 checkout data transfer, need order id on place order

Tags: orders, magento2.4, place-order

I have an external service that i want to use it in some parts of magento 2.4 checkout page. I can do it well, so, my problem is: I can not get data after pressing submit order, because magento generates order number after redirecting from payment page.
So my question is that, how can I get order number on order place? my external service, holds some data of product but if I don't have order id I can not get those datas.

Comment: Which payment method?

Comment: @SohelRana any payment, custom payment

Comment: Use checkout_submit_all_after for all payment methods and for paypal use paypal_express_place_order_success event. Both events are fire after order place.

Answer (score 2):

You can event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action this will help you to get all the data related to the order

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="vendor_module_observer_frontend_checkout_onepagecontrollersuccessaction_checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Frontend\Checkout\OnepageControllerSuccessAction"/>
</event>
</config>
```

And create observer for the same

```
<?php
 declare(strict_types=1);

 namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Frontend\Checkout;

 class OnepageControllerSuccessAction implements 
 \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
 {

     /**
      * Execute observer
      *
      * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
      * @return void
      */
      public function execute(
      \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
       ) {
        //Your observer code
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce, I need Incremental_id before success, before redirecting

Comment: $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();